# How can I add a picture as folder background in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, nautilus

How could I add a picture as folder background?

For example if I have a movie folder, how I could add its poster as background in this folder?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

This function has been removed in the latest Nautilus that is part of Gnome3. This means that this is not at all possible with now, at least not by default, and I could not find any plugins that would make it possible otherwise.

The other, similar file managers like Marlin and Thunar do not have this function either. The KDE file manager, Dolphin, does not, to my knowledge, have this, or at least not by default.

Sorry, but it appears that none allow this right now.